# is there any date picker package in react-native which supports entering date manually as shown in the image?

Tags: react-native, datepicker

[image]

Usually date pickers allow users to select any date from the calendar. Besides to that I want to allow user to enter date manually as shown in the image.

Can anybody suggests any RN package that suits my requirement?. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a masked text input.

Try using this iMask.js - it's very powerful!
https://imask.js.org

With this react-native wrapper for it:
https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs/tree/master/packages/react-native-imask

Then it's just a matter of:

```
<IMaskTextInput
  value={someValue}
  mask={Date}
  min={new Date(1990, 0, 1)}
  max={new Date()} // today
  lazy={false}
  onAccept={(value, mask) => console.log(value)}
/>
```

See docs of both libraries for more config details.
You can easily extend your own custom TextInput with masking functionality using this wrapper.

Comment: seems like thi sis react package. Does it support to react-native? Any example code on how to use it with any date picker?

Comment: ah dang it! i was meant to give a link to a react native wrapper. Let me just edit the answer